# std::string insert method has ambiguous overloads?

Tags: c++, stl, stlport

Environment: VS2005 C++ using STLPort 5.1.4.

Compiling the following code snippet:

```
std::string copied = "asdf";
char ch = 's';
copied.insert(0,1,ch);
```

I receive an error:

```
Error   1   error C2668: 'stlpx_std::basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>::insert' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

It appears that the problem is the insert method call on the string object.

The two defined overloads are

```
void insert ( iterator p, size_t n, char c );
string& insert ( size_t pos1, size_t n, char c );
```

But given that STLPort uses a simple char* as its iterator, the literal zero in the insert method in my code is ambiguous.

So while I can easily overcome the problem by *hinting* such as

```
copied.insert(size_t(0),1,ch);
```

My question is: is this overloading and possible ambiguity intentional in the specification?  Or more likely an unintended side-effect of the specific STLPort implementation?

(Note that the Microsoft-supplied STL does not have this problem as it has a class for the iterator, instead of a naked pointer)

Comment: To be any more strict: it should be `copied.insert(static_cast<size_t>(0), static_cast<size_t>(1), ch)`

Comment: @ereOn:  The second `static_cast` is unnecessary since both overloads take a `size_t` as the second parameter.

Comment: Not unnecessary because of possible future overloads and the uncertain integral type of '1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue, ruled "Not A Defect". http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#84

Answer (score 0):

If you differentiate the differents integers type, there is no ambiguity *at all*.

Good practices commands to store buffer sizes in `size_t` (or `ssize_t`) types, not `int`.

If you agree with that, calling `insert(int, int, char)` makes no sense since the two first arguments are supposed to be a "buffer sizes".

If there was no implicit conversion from `int` to `size_t`, you couldn't even call `insert()` that way.

Answer (score 0):

Intentional or not, the problem has more to do with the semantics of `0` than the member functions in question. Perhaps the Microsoft library's designers (they used Dinkumware last time I checked) were more cautious in this respect.

Comment: Dinkumware would probably not have this issue: using real iterators alleviate the ambiguity.